# .htaccess 301 redirect with same path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
Redirect 301 /exampleDomain/ http://www.example.com/exampleDomainChanged/

Redirect 301 /exampleDomain/more/ http://example.com/changedMore/more1
```

exampleDomain is firstly changed into exampleDomainChanged but the problem is with the second URL, /exampleDomain/more/ "exampleDomain" is already changed to exampleDomainChanged

but I need it to be "changedMore" in this case.

What rewrite rules I have to apply here in .htaccess?

I tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

but it gives too many redirects on index page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need list the most specific rules at the top.

If you swap out the rules, this should work as expected.

```
Redirect 301 /exampleDomain/more/ http://example.com/changedMore/more1

Redirect 301 /exampleDomain/ http://www.example.com/exampleDomainChanged/
```